# LVM: how to strip Logical volume without impacting existing data?

Tags: lvm

I have an LV lv1 backed up by a VG vg1 using 2 PV pv1 and pv2.

From `lvs` I understand that the layout of the LV is linear:

```
# lvs -o+lv_layout,stripes
  LV               VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Layout     #Str
linear        1
  lv1           vg_HDD -wi-ao---- <10,43t                                                     linear        1
  lv1           vg_HDD -wi-ao---- <10,43t                                                     linear        1
  lv1           vg_HDD -wi-ao---- <10,43t
```

I understand that I have to convert the PVs with `lvconvert --type striped lv1`

But I don't know:

1. if this will impact the data?
2. this does what I want e.g strip the datas written to pv1 and pv2 in order to take advantage of the two disks as a raid0 would do.

Thanks for any help!